# Filtering Django ModelViewSet List From Url Parameter

Tags: python, django, url, keyword-argument, django-rest-viewsets

Hi I have a model like:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My View looks like:

```
class AppointmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
```

In my urls:

```
router.register(r'appointments', AppointmentViewSet)
```

Now I want to filter the list of appointments by some patient id. This id should be given by the requester through url. I'm thinking about using **kwargs** to catch it. But I have no idea how to do it. I know I have to override the **list** method.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # what do I write here? so that the queryset would be filtered by patient id sent through the url?
```

How do I customize the **url** and/or the **view** to accommodate the patient id parameter? I just want to modify the list request, all other actions(create, details, destroy) should be handled by the modelviewset's default behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: After providing the id, you need an instance or a list?

Comment: a list. list of appointments.

Comment: You're passing the id from the url, right?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

I've added an url entry like this:

```
url(r'appointments/ofpatient/(?P<patient>\d+)', AppointmentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
```

Which I can call from the browser as:

```
http://localhost:8000/appointments/ofpatient/6
```

and in view:

```
def list(self, request, patient=None):
    if patient:
        patient = Patient.active.filter(id=patient)
        appts = Appointment.active.order_by('appt_time').filter(patient=patient)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(appts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        appts = Appointment.active.order_by('appt_time')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(appts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In this way, the /appointments url is also preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom method to handle the routing for the url with the patient id:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route
rom rest_framework.response import Response

class AppointmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @list_route()
    def patient_appointments(self, request, id=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset.filter(patient_id=id), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The `list_route` decorator marks your method as requiring routing.

**Update:**

You can manually register the url as:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/appointments/$', AppointmentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'patient_appointments'}), name='patient-appointments')
```

Comment: how should my request url look like in this case?

Comment: you mean <app_name>/appointments/<id>? but that has a problem. this url format is supposed to provide the 'detail' view. how would i pass the patient id through it?

Comment: It does not clash with the detail view, there is a trailing `appointments`. I suggest you try this out first before second guessing. If you have any errors/problems, report back.

Comment: i tried with this url:
url(r'(\d+)/appointments/', AppointmentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})), but it ignores the id at the beginning and gives me all the records

Comment: I've updated the answer. The view should be constructed from the `patient_appointments` method, not `list`, but I'm not sure why you want to write the url conf yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(self.request.get('pid')):
    pk = self.request.get('pid')
    all_appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__pk=pk)
```

for patients url would be `appoinment/?pid=9`

and for appointment details `appoinment/9`

Comment: what do i write in the url then? how should i issue the request?

Comment: as you said you want to pass id, so appointment/1 or 2 anything like that

Comment: but as i'm using modelviewset, any id after appointments is treated as the id of the appointment record itself, not the patient id.

Comment: ok so you can do one thing you can get the patients id from the appointment id and then can filter according to that users id

Comment: actually i'm trying to retrieve all the appointments a patient has. so the patient id must be obtained first.

Comment: tell me a thing bro if you pass like patient id 9 and get the pk and filter the objects like the one i gave, it will give you the appointment list of that user, the pk will be treated as appointment or something else doesnt matter, you will filter the query according to user id, so you dont need to think about it

Comment: if i understood correctly you are suggesting to do something like: servername/appointments/9. right? then treat that 9 as the patient id? but the same link has to work for appointment details itself too. for example: if an appointment record has id 9, then it has to be called like that.

Comment: apparently, it ignores the 'pid' part and calls the appointment details view.

Comment: sorry bro, made a little mistake, try the edited ans